# How to fix "TypeError: argument of type 'ConnectionHandler' is not iterable" when running a django test?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-unittest, django-custom-user

When I do ```python -m unittest`` inside of my users app, I get this error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'ConnectionHandler' is not iterable
```

I was customizing my User model in django and I wanted to make a test for it. I already did the migrations and the custom User model works good (I did with a new database), so I expected to run the test successfully. Here is my test code:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

# Create your tests here.
class UsersManagersTests(TestCase):

    def test_create_user(self):
        User = get_user_model()
        user = User.objects.create_user(email='normal@user.com', password='foo')
        self.assertEqual(user.email, 'normal@user.com')
        self.assertTrue(user.is_active)
        self.assertFalse(user.is_staff)
        self.assertFalse(user.is_superuser)
        try:
            # username is None for the AbstractUser option
            # username does not exist for the AbstractBaseUser option
            self.assertIsNone(user.username)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            User.objects.create_user()
        with self.assertRaises(TypeError):
            User.objects.create_user(email='')
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            User.objects.create_user(email='', password="foo")

    def test_create_superuser(self):
        User = get_user_model()
        admin_user = User.objects.create_superuser('super@user.com', 'foo')
        self.assertEqual(admin_user.email, 'super@user.com')
        self.assertTrue(admin_user.is_active)
        self.assertTrue(admin_user.is_staff)
        self.assertTrue(admin_user.is_superuser)
        try:
            # username is None for the AbstractUser option
            # username does not exist for the AbstractBaseUser option
            self.assertIsNone(admin_user.username)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
            User.objects.create_superuser(
                email='super@user.com', password='foo', is_superuser=False)
```

settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.utils import timezone

from .managers import CustomUserManager

# Create your models here.
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
        ('O', 'Others'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

managers.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
    for authentication instead of usernames.
    """
    def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a User with the given email and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
        """
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
        return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

Why does the test fail?

Answer (score 4):

The error is probably due to the configuration of your IDE. 
What happens when you run "python manage.py test" ?

Comment: In manage.py path, I ran that command and I get: ```Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.575s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
``` So I'm not sure if the test is running correctly or not

Comment: It is actually running, if you do "python manage.py test -v 2 " you will have more precision !

Comment: Thanks!, so by last, what is the difference between these two commands? "python -m unittest" and "python manage.py test"?

Comment: "python -m unittest" invokes the automatic test discovery from the unittest module (Python standard library) while "python manage.py test" runs the manage script provided by Django which then runs your unit tests. I do not know how exactly these two methods differ, but I guess with Django you would want to use the manage script.